# How can I display Firebase data on refreshing while using ion-refresher?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have some asynchronous data in my Firbase database.I have used `ion-refresher` in the .html file. But when I am adding new data to firebase database,then the data gets loaded there and is simultaneously displayed in the view.I cannot make use of `ion-refresher`.How can I make so?

Code:

### .html

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
      <ion-refresher-content refreshingText="Refreshing...">
      </ion-refresher-content>
      </ion-refresher>
  <ion-list>

      <ion-item *ngFor="let data of datas | async" class="pqr">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
          <img src="assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        {{data.Comp}}<br> {{data.Demand}}
        <br>
        <p> {{data.Desig}}<br></p>
        {{data.Place}}<br> {{data.when}}
        <br>
      </ion-item>
```

### .ts

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  datas: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  // datas: FirebaseListObservable<Item[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authData: AuthData, public af: AngularFire) {
    //this.loadData();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.datas = this.af.database.list('/datas');
  }

   doRefresh(refresher) {
   console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

  setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what data you need to load.But here is how to do your thing.
You if you call whatever your data loading methods inside the constructor ior `ngOnInit()` it may load the data when you load the page.

To use ion refresher just call whatever data loading method inside the refresher method.

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
   console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

  setTimeout(() => {

  loaddata();             //<-call your data load method here

  console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
   }
```

also look at here  https://alligator.io/ionic/refresher-ionic/